# libgit2: git_clone() fails with a "failed to create ssl object" error

Tags: c++, libgit2

I'm trying to clone a git repository using libgit2's `git_clone()` function, however, when I call the function it returns -1, and using `giterr_last()` (I get "undefined reference" if I use `git_error_latest()`, not sure why) I get the error "failed to create ssl object".

I've looked into the source code for the relevant file, [here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/src/streams/openssl.c), and it seems as though it fails on line 711, `SSL_new(git__ssl_ctx)`.

Here's my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <git2/clone.h>
#include <git2/errors.h>
#include <git2/common.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    git_repository* pGitRepository = nullptr;
    std::string url = "https://github.com/Newbie13XD/nashmap.git";
    std::string path = "/home/neboula/CLionProjects/gut/foo";
    const git_clone_options* options = nullptr;

    if (git_clone(&pGitRepository, url.c_str(), path.c_str(), options) != 0) {
        const git_error* error = giterr_last();

        std::cout << error->message;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with g++ (version: Red Hat 8.3.1-2) and libgit2 version 0.27.8.

Comment: the posted code is written in C++, not C.  Please remove the 'c' tag

Comment: I do not find: `int git_clone_init_options( git_clone_options *opts, unsigned int version );`

Comment: What SSL library are you targeting?  What version?

Comment: @EdwardThomson OpenSSL version 1.1.1b (or so I think anyway, it's libgit2 who requires it, not me, but OpenSSL is what I can find installed on my machine)

Comment: @user3629249 I'm not entirely sure how I would use that, additional note, [the documentation](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#v0.24.2/group/clone/git_clone) states that NULL can be passed, and neither can I quite figure out how it wants me to format the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, you have to call `git_libgit2_init()` prior to using any other functions in libgit2. Adding this to the start of my program solved the issue.